# simple Mov issue in Assmbly programming

Tags: assembly

I have a small problem in my program, I'm new to Assembly and trying to track the program and the cpu registers in intel 80x86, but the problem that when I run this code

```
.model small 
.data
array dw 1122H,3344H,5566H,6677H
.code 
mov bx,1
mov si,6
mov ax,array[bx][si-2]
```

`AX` suppose to have a value but its value is 0
Anyone can tell whay the value of `AX` should have after run the program
and why `AX` has no value??

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: @RobertHarvey My question is very simple and is not complicated at all, and have enough information, Really I don't know why you pause my question!! >>> although I try to edit it, hope I gave more information this time

Comment: Your last line does not make sense. `array` is a one-dimensional array, but you're treating it like it's two-dimensional.

Comment: What value do you expect ax to have?

Comment: You need to share more of your code. I assume you are using a 16bit assembler, my first guess is that your DS is not correctly initialized and you are therefore looking at the wrong area of memory. Looking at the code you should be getting 0x7755 in AX. One caveat is that I have not used a 16 bit assembler in years, but similar code in a recent version of masm (ml.exe) will work if you change the registers to 32bit equivalents.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: That's just quirky syntax. `array[bx][si-2]` is simply a more confusing (IMO) way of writing `[bx + si + array-2]`. Whether or not that was understood by the OP, I don't know.

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before